# C2244: 'MyTemplateClass<T>::MyFunction': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

Could someone explain why the following code compiles on GCC, but not in Visual Studio.

I get *error C2244: 'MyTemplate::List': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration* at the noted line.

```
#include <array>

enum class MyEnum
{
    MAX = 5,
};

template<typename E> 
class MyTemplate
{
public :
    static const int NUMBER = static_cast<int>(E::MAX);
    std::array<int, NUMBER> List(); 
};

template<typename E>
std::array<int, MyTemplate<E>::NUMBER> MyTemplate<E>::List() // ERROR
{
    return std::array<int, MyTemplate<E>::NUMBER>();
}

int main()
{
    MyTemplate<MyEnum> myClass;
}
```

I presume it's something non-standard I'm doing that GCC allows and VS doesn't, but I can't figure out what. CLion is also happy with the code.

Given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521073/msvcerror-c2244-unable-to-match-function-definition-to-an-existing-declaratio) answer it's also possible it's a bug in VS, although the specifics are different, the error message is the same. In my case the template seems simple however, involving one parameter and no nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, you might use:

```
template<typename E>
auto MyTemplate<E>::List()
-> std::array<int, NUMBER>
{
    return std::array<int, MyTemplate<E>::NUMBER>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEhabzEr5)